# How to Disable Context menu of the Web Browser control in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, browser, designmode

I have a web browser control which show a html local document (EPUB Files) , i would like to turn off right clicks and turn off context menu to unable "Cut" & "Paste" because my web browser is in Design Mode ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can disable default context menu by setting IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled attribute of WebBrowser to false, then you can create a context menu programmatically and add it to MenuItems List of the WebBrowser.
You can find more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15808019/manipulate-selected-text-on-wpf-webbrowser/15810043#15810043)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).